# Ember CLI pod structure - place extra templates in each pod

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've just migrated an Ember app to use the pod structure by adding the `podModulePrefix` property to my application. All route templates, the controller backing the route template, and the route itself exist under:

```
app/
  modules/
    route_name/
         template.hbs
         controller.js
         route.js
```

Now I do a lot of manually switching out of templates with named outlets. So the route template may contain two named outlets, and there's 4 or 5 templates that can be rendered into these outlets at any one time. As of now, these extra templates are sitting in the Ember-CLI created templates directory:

```
app/
  templates/
     route_name/
        temp1
        temp2
```

One action that might exist on a route of mine could contain this call:

```
this.render('route_name/temp1', {outlet: 'named', into: 'route_name'});
```

What are the steps necessary to make it so templates placed in a templates folder on a pod are resolvable:

```
app/
  modules/
    route_name/
       template.hbs
       controller.js
       route.js
       templates/
         temp1
```

And how would I then reference `temp1` in `this.render()`?

Comment: I'm interested too! ... pods are good idea, some more details on organization would be great. I also tried (the equivalent of) `template.temp1.hbs`, but didn't seem to work

Answer (score 6):

This is done by creating a folder with the name you want and putting `template.hbs` inside.

```
app/
  modules/
    route_name/
       template.hbs
       controller.js
       route.js
       temp1/
         template.hbs
```

Pods are not all or nothing, so you can also create a template in:

```
app/
  modules/
    ...
  templates/
    route_name/
      temp1.hbs
```

The resolver will first look in pod path, then fall back to 'traditional' locations. To see this happening, you can enable `ENV.APP.LOG_RESOLVER = true;` in your `environment.js`